# Retrieving likelihood from an altered coxph object

Tags: cox-model

I am somewhat of a new user of R. I want to do the following:

1. start with a fitted Cox Proportional Hazards model( fit using coxph), call this model 1
2. set a few of the coefficients of model 1 to zero
3. recompute the likelihood with these coeffcients set to zero. Note that I do not want to refit the model

Is there a method which does this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A Cox model does not have a likelihood.

Comment: OK, partial likelihood

Comment: How would you propose to do the corresponding task in a linear regression (logical steps, independent of R coding)? What is the difficulty with re-fitting the model?